# How to generate 3D helix in MATLAB or Python?

Tags: python, matlab, 3d, figure, helix

I have written a code to generate x, y, z points of a helix and got this result:

[image: What I got]

Code:

```matlab
clear all; delete all, clc;
% Spiral constants
THETA_0 = 5; % constant
THETA_1 = 10.3; % starting angle
A = 3.762;
B = 0.001317;
C = 7.967;
D = 0.1287;
E = 0.003056;

s=2;
% Calculate (x,y,z) coordinates of points defining the spiral path
theta = THETA_1:.1:910.3;  % range, starting degree angle:final degree angle
for i = 1:length(theta)
    if (theta(i)<=99.9)
        R(i) = C*(1-D*log(theta(i)-THETA_0));
    else
%       theta_mod = 0.0002*theta(i)^2+.98*theta(i);
        R(i) = A*exp(-B*theta(i));
    end
    % scaling 
    x(i) = s*R(i)*cosd(theta(i));
    y(i) = s*R(i)*sind(theta(i));
    z(i) = s*E*(theta(i)-THETA_1);
end

helix=animatedline('LineWidth',2);
axis equal;
axis vis3d;
% set (gca,'XLim', [-5 5],'YLim', [-10 10], 'ZLim',[0 6])
view(43,24);
hold on;
for i=1:length(z)
    addpoints(helix, x(i),y(i),z(i));
    head=scatter3 (x(i),y(i),z(i));
    drawnow
%   pause(0.01);
    delete(head);
end
```

and I want a helical structure around it similar to this

[image: Intended 3D]

Comment: Please provide the code, you have written so far, so that others have a starting point to help ypu. Also, what have you tried so far, solving your problem on your own?

Comment: I was trying to make 2 cylinders around but didn't work.

Comment: You should keep the radius in the x-y plane constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second picture give you:

- The parametric equations for x,y and z.
- The restriction on `u` and `v`

You have all the necessary informations to create your geometry:

```
%plot the mesh
u=linspace(0,4*pi,50);
v=linspace(0,2*pi,50);
[u,v]=meshgrid(u,v);
x=(1.2+0.5*cos(v)).*cos(u);
y=(1.2+0.5*cos(v)).*sin(u);
z=0.5*sin(v)+u/pi;
surf(x,y,z)
hold on

%plot the 3d line
u = linspace(0,4*pi,40)
x=1.2.*cos(u);
y=1.2.*sin(u);
z=u/pi;
plot3(x,y,z,'r');

axis equal
```

Now you just have to adjust the parametric equations to fit your line.

[image]

**EDIT:**
To apply the same solution to your specific case you simply have to replace `u` and `v` with your `theta` and `R` variable in the `meshgrid` function:

```
THETA_0 = 5; % constant
THETA_1 = 10.3; % starting angle
A = 3.762;
B = 0.001317;
C = 7.967;
D = 0.1287;
E = 0.003056;

s=2;
% Calculate (x,y,z) coordinates of points defining the spiral path
theta = THETA_1:5:910.3;
for i = 1:length(theta)
    if (theta(i)<=99.9)
        R(i) = s*C*(1-D*log(theta(i)-THETA_0));
    else
        R(i) = s*A*exp(-B*theta(i));
    end

end

x = R.*cosd(theta);
y = R.*sind(theta);
z = E.*(theta-THETA_1);
plot3(x,y,z,'r','linewidth',2)

hold on
[u,v]=meshgrid(theta,R);
x=(R+0.5*cos(v)).*cosd(u);
y=(R+0.5*cos(v)).*sind(u);
z=0.5*sin(v)+E.*(u-THETA_1);
mesh(x,y,z,'facecolor','none')

axis equal
```

**Result:**

[image]

by the way I'm not a big fan of mixing `cosd` and `cos` in the same script, but do what you want.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. In the first of my figures for which I wrote the MATLAB program, I only have x,y,z points, how to get u and v points for it? That would draw a tube around the helix with radius r like you did in your answer. Thanks

Comment: @NHB check my edit, nothing change, you just have to replace u and v with your value.

Comment: Thank you for the update. R is a vector in my case. These two statements are not working x=(R+0.5*cos(v)).*cosd(u);
y=(R+0.5*cos(v)).*sind(u);

Comment: Your matlab version does not support implicit expansion: check this link https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html

Comment: Thank you very much. It was really helpful. I appreciate your time.

Comment: One more questions if I may, can you guide me to get variable diameter of the tube at different position of spiral?

Comment: @NHB it look like you don't understand how work those parametric equations. It's useless to just copy-paste a code without understanding the math behind. Once you've figured out how it work you should be able to get a variable diameter in less than a minute. Also accept this answer as the solution since it give the solution to your initial question.

Answer (score 1):

Spent some time looking for this and wanted to share a copy of the code with more comments on what each variable does. Please correct me if I have them wrong but I've played with the code and this seems about right. Hope this helps others who end up looking for some more detail because its been a while since Calculus III :)

```
    %% 3D Helical Curve
    % tested on MATLAB R2018a
    % See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/55126315/11895567
    % See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/55119694/11895567
    %
    % Code is in the state used to obtain the second of the two images shown below
    clear, clc, close all
    format compact
    
    %% Input Parameters
    res = 25;   % plot resolution; higher -> finer resolution
    R = 0.15;   % wire radius
    r = 4;      % radius to wire centerline
    t = 3;      % number of coils
    
    %% Surface of the wire
    a = 3;  % scalar for resolutoin for surface.u to make it look nicer
    b = 2;  % Set to 2 for upper and lower surfaces. Set to 1 for upper surface only
    
    surface.u = linspace(0, t*2*pi, a*res); % Path of the wire surface
    surface.v = linspace(0, b*pi, res);     % Wire surface
    [surface.u, surface.v] = meshgrid(surface.u, surface.v);
    
    surface.x = (r + R*cos(surface.v)).*cos(surface.u);
    surface.y = (r + R*cos(surface.v)).*sin(surface.u);
    surface.z = R*sin(surface.v) + surface.u/pi;
    
    %% Center line of the wire
    c = a;  % scalar for resolution for line.u to make it look nicer
    
    line.u = linspace(0, t*2*pi, c*res);
    line.x = r.*cos(line.u);
    line.y = r.*sin(line.u);
    line.z = line.u/pi;
    
    %% Plotting
    f = figure();
    grid on
    hold on
    plot3(line.x, line.y, line.z, 'r');
    surf(surface.x, surface.y, surface.z)
    view(45, 12);   % Azimuth = 45, Elevation = 12
    axis equal
```

Samples (assume units are millimeters):

1. Inputs: `R = 0.25`, `r = 1`, `t = 1`, `res = 25`

- Wire radius, `R`, is 0.25mm
- coil radius, `r`, is 1mm
- number of coils, `t`, is 1 (unitless)
- plot resolution, `res`, is 25 (unitless)

[image]

2. Inputs: `R = 0.15`, `r = 4`, `t = 3`, `res = 25`

- Wire radius, `R`, is 0.15mm
- coil radius, `r`, is 4mm
- number of coils, `t`, is 3 (unitless)
- plot resolution, `res`, is 25 (unitless)

[image]